# SQL Server Parse Nested JSON into Key Value Pairs

Tags: json, sql-server, parsing, ssis

I have a JSON file that looks like the following:

```
{
"101010": {
    "ChassisHostname": "host1", 
    "Slot1": {
        "BootROMVersion": "v1", 
        "ControllerType": "controller", 
        "ControllerVersion": "v6", 
        "FirmwareVersion": "v6", 
        "InstalledKeys": "Plus", 
        "Port0": {
            "BannerDelayTime": "2 seconds", 
            "BootImage": "Image1", 
            "BootSkipDelayTime": "5 seconds", 
            "BootType": "UEFI", 
            "ChangeMac": "Default", 
            "EventMergeTimeout": "1500 nanoseconds", 
            "FirmwareVariant": "Auto", 
            "InsecureFilters": "Default", 
            "Link-UpDelayTime": "5 seconds", 
            "LinkSpeed": "Negotiated automatically", 
            "MacAddress": "00-00-00-00-00-00", 
            "MacSpoofing": "Default", 
            "PfMsi-XInterruptLimit": "12", 
            "PhysicalFunctionsOnThisPort": "1", 
            "PortMode": "Default", 
            "SwitchMode": "Default", 
            "VfMsi-XInterruptLimit": "2", 
            "VirtualFunctionsOnEachPf": "0", 
            "VlanTags": "None"
        }, 
        "Port1": {
            "BannerDelayTime": "2 seconds", 
            "BootImage": "Image1", 
            "BootSkipDelayTime": "5 seconds", 
            "BootType": "UEFI", 
            "ChangeMac": "Default", 
            "EventMergeTimeout": "1500 nanoseconds", 
            "FirmwareVariant": "Auto", 
            "InsecureFilters": "Default", 
            "Link-UpDelayTime": "5 seconds", 
            "LinkSpeed": "Negotiated automatically", 
            "MacAddress": "00-00-00-00-00-00", 
            "MacSpoofing": "Default", 
            "PfMsi-XInterruptLimit": "12", 
            "PhysicalFunctionsOnThisPort": "1", 
            "PortMode": "Default", 
            "SwitchMode": "Default", 
            "VfMsi-XInterruptLimit": "2", 
            "VirtualFunctionsOnEachPf": "0", 
            "VlanTags": "None"
        }, 
        "ProductName": "Product", 
        "SerialNumber": "10101010"
    }, 
    "Slot4": {
        "BootROMVersion": "v1", 
        "ControllerType": "controller", 
        "ControllerVersion": "v6", 
        "FirmwareVersion": "v6", 
        "InstalledKeys": "Plus", 
        "Port0": {
            "BannerDelayTime": "2 seconds", 
            "BootImage": "Image1", 
            "BootSkipDelayTime": "5 seconds", 
            "BootType": "UEFI", 
            "ChangeMac": "Default", 
            "EventMergeTimeout": "1500 nanoseconds", 
            "FirmwareVariant": "Auto", 
            "InsecureFilters": "Default", 
            "Link-UpDelayTime": "5 seconds", 
            "LinkSpeed": "Negotiated automatically", 
            "MacAddress": "00-00-00-00-00-00", 
            "MacSpoofing": "Default", 
            "PfMsi-XInterruptLimit": "12", 
            "PhysicalFunctionsOnThisPort": "1", 
            "PortMode": "Default", 
            "SwitchMode": "Default", 
            "VfMsi-XInterruptLimit": "2", 
            "VirtualFunctionsOnEachPf": "0", 
            "VlanTags": "None"
        }, 
        "Port1": {
            "BannerDelayTime": "2 seconds", 
            "BootImage": "Image1", 
            "BootSkipDelayTime": "5 seconds", 
            "BootType": "UEFI", 
            "ChangeMac": "Default", 
            "EventMergeTimeout": "1500 nanoseconds", 
            "FirmwareVariant": "Auto", 
            "InsecureFilters": "Default", 
            "Link-UpDelayTime": "5 seconds", 
            "LinkSpeed": "Negotiated automatically", 
            "MacAddress": "00-00-00-00-00-00", 
            "MacSpoofing": "Default", 
            "PfMsi-XInterruptLimit": "12", 
            "PhysicalFunctionsOnThisPort": "1", 
            "PortMode": "Default", 
            "SwitchMode": "Default", 
            "VfMsi-XInterruptLimit": "2", 
            "VirtualFunctionsOnEachPf": "0", 
            "VlanTags": "None"
        }, 
        "ProductName": "Product", 
        "SerialNumber": "10101010"
    }
}
```

Currently, I bring this data in using SSIS, by putting the entire JSON text in a single column and reading it using OPENJSON. That code looks like this:

```
DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @json= (SELECT TOP 1 [JSON] FROM [STG_Table])

SELECT *
FROM OPENJSON(@json);
```

Since the JSON files I have are consistent in schema, I need a way to parse these files into key value pairs based on serial number. I will do this using a trigger upon import with SSIS. As it stands, I know OPENJSON really only gets the values into columns, so I'm assuming I will need to unpivot the data afterwards. Can anybody point me in the right direction to do this?

Comment: I would deserialize in a C# script component and then send the data to a normalized table structure

Comment: I have tried this in the past. I remember I ran into an issue cause SSIS does not support the Nuget package that allows you to do that,